# Failed Cannot connect to 'Mentor Graphics ModelSim' HDL simulator

Tags: matlab, simulink, modelsim, hdl-coder

I am trying to perform `cosimulation` in HDL Coder using ModelSim 10.2c .But getting below error :

`Failed Cannot connect to 'Mentor Graphics ModelSim' HDL simulator`

Does any one know what could be reason of this error please?

Thanks a lot